# How do I create rows in a table based off a cell value and fill a column also based off the cell values in Excel

Tags: excel

I am looking to create and fill a table based on two cell values.
If D2 and E2 contain the values 64 and 8 respectively. I want to create a column in a table that has 64X8 rows (not a 64x8 table). Then I want to fill the column with values 0-63 and repeat 8 times.

For example, the table will have a column with values:

```html
0
1
2
3
4
...
63
0
1
2
3
4
...
63
```

The 0-63 pattern repeating 8 times.

Is this possible? Sorry if my explanation isn't clear. I can provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=MOD(SEQUENCE(D2*E2,,0),D2)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to fill another column so that next to each repeat of the 0-63 range the number in the column goes up by one? For example, the first 0-63 will have 0 next to all the values, and the next 0-63 will have 1 next to all the values ....

Comment: I think then need another formula.